# Discord JS Commands Ran At Once

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a discord Vouch System but when i do **-Vouch** it runs 2 commands one is **-Vouch** And the other is **-Vouches** ```

```
client.on("message", (message) => {

    if (message.content.startsWith("-Vouches")) {
                  const user = message.mentions.users.first();
          if (user === undefined) {
    return; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always uses `startsWith` it will surely execute two commands if one of the command name is contained into another one.

For example, if we have this code :

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!test")) console.log("test command");

    if (message.content.startsWith("!test2")) console.log("test2 command");
});
```

Both command will be executed if we write `!test`.

So a solution vastly used is to split the message by spaces, then take the first word, and test it, not if it starts with a string, test the entire string, like this.

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    const [commandName, ...arguments] = message.content.split(/\s+/);
    // commandName is the first word
    // arguments is an array of the other words of the message

    if (commandName === "!test") console.log("test command");

    if (commandName === "!test2") console.log("test2 command");
});
```

Here we split the message by spaces, using the regular expression `\s+`, then took the first word and tested it directly.
You can also then use the array `arguments` for your commands stuff.